# Assign multiple ids

Tags: jquery, html

I have two different forms one for entry and another for update the same.so i did take

```
<form id="form1" action="action.do">
<input type="text" id="a" value="1">
</form>
```

and

```
<form id="form2" action="action.do">
<input type="text" id="a" value="2">
</form>
```

I have to access both inputs.I did try like `var inputs=$('#form1 #a,#form2 #a').val();`

form2 input value is not retrieved.How do i fetch values when form ids are similar but input ids are different with single jquery function ?

Comment: You're not allowed to have two elements in a single document with the same ID.

Comment: though they are enclosed with in different form ids ?

Comment: You said in your question the "form ids are similar but input ids are different", however your code gives exactly the opposite. Check again and update with the corrected information, because the answer from @KarlAndréGagnon is correct according to your code.

Answer (score 1):

*Although ID should be unique, that is not the problem here, you should still change them for a class. It will also simplify your selector.*

When using `.val()` as a getter, it will not get every value of your stack, but only the value of the first element. If you want to have an array of value, you should use `.map()`.

```
var inputs=$('#form1 #a,#form2 #a').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

You need to end with `.get()` since `.map()` return a jQuery object. `.get()` will change it for a native JS array.

Comment: It does not worked for me.Give me an demo in jsfiddle

Comment: Above jsfiddle two different forms input values are accessed at a time.But in my case one form will be accessed one after the other but not both at a time. I did try with replacing above snippet it does not worked

Comment: Now, you completely lost me. Can't you do `$('#form1 #a')` when you need to use the first one and `$('#form2 #a')` to use the second ones?

Comment: yes.but i have to replicate code for datepicker.because datepicker function should call on form1 and form2.